# How can I create automated campaigns from facebook api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I want to create facebook campaigns with App Install Campaign Type as automated app ads[image]

But when I put objective as APP_INSTALLS it goes to bottom one app_ads  from api .

Right now this is my facebook request params

```
"name": "Some name",
"status" : "PAUSED",
"objective" : "APP_INSTALLS",
"buying_type" : "AUCTION",
"special_ad_categories" : "NONE",
```